# What's the difference between Publish (Click Once) from the context menu and from the Project properties page in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

I have a Windows GUI client I've written in C# using Visual Studio 2010. When I publish from the project's Property Page it fails whilst it succeeds from the context menu on the project. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: Weird problem. Do you see the same issue with a blank project?

Comment: A blank project? Would that even compile!? :P

Comment: Uh, yeah. Go to File -> New Project. Select a "Windows Forms Application" from the dialog, and click "OK". Compiles just fine.

Comment: Aha. Yeah, tried that and it failed so I thought perhaps you meant a project without any files and anticipated the compiler complaining about not having an entry point. Thus the problem remains weird.

Comment: Exactly the same issue in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer for this from the ClickOnce team at Microsoft.

When you use the publish option on the build menu, it totally circumvents anything in Visual Studio and uses msbuild directly. If you use the Publish button on the Publish tab, any add-ins that the user has installed impact the process of doing the build and publish (he said something like "it goes through VIsual Studio before getting to msbuild"). So using the Build menu is always better.