# How do I get a console application to check for updates without using ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, console-application, auto-update

In a normal Windows application I can use...
`System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate()`
...to determine whether or not there is an update available.

I know I can use `System.Reflection` and `Assembly` and `AssemblyName` to print the version of the application as it is currently running, but I don't know how to get it to compare that to what's been published most recently.

What is the equivalent to `CheckForUpdate()` for a console application, without using ClickOnce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need something server side that the application can use to find out what the most recent version is.  Personally, I would go with a web service that returns the most recent version number and a url where it can be downloaded, but this could also be done with a static page that gets parsed for this information.  The application starts up, checks it's version number to the one returned from the service.  If the service reports a newer version use HttpWebRequest (or other method) to download the new version.  If the new version is packaged as an installer you could then execute the installer and exit the currently running instance.  If you want something more silent than an installer you will need a way of updating your exe in place.  This is usually done by a 2nd application (the updater) that waits for the main application to exit and moves the new version of the exe in to place, then restarts the application.  One thing to keep in mind is that for this to work the user that the application is running as will need to have permission to write to the program directory.

If this is more of a corporate environment where you want to use fileshares you could do it differently.  Have the program check a well known shared directory for a text file with the most recent version and the path to the update.  Parse the text file for the information the same as above, and grab the new version from the specified path using the `system.io` namespace classes.  It's basically the same operation, but using file paths instead of web requests.

Comment: This is definitely a corp. environment. In VS2010 if you open the solution properties and go to Publish you can click Updates... and use that to specify where the program should check for updates. The trouble is that this method doesn't allow users to defer updates and it requires the user to open the app twice before the update is installed. In a Windows app you can use `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateAsync()` to force an update and then close the app once it's done. I find it hard to believe that console apps don't have something similar.

Comment: My understanding is that all of that relies on the ClickOnce framework which you said you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Well then clearly I have been misinformed about ClickOnce.  If I am currently using it in my Windows apps then I never realized it.  lol

Comment: It's entirely possible that I'm wrong, and the publish options use something different.  I'm looking at it in more depth now.

Comment: I was able to find this other StackOverflow question and answer that indicates that the Publish Properties Page is just another method of accessing ClickOnce.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617046/whats-the-difference-between-publish-click-once-from-the-context-menu-and-fro

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/748fh114.aspx also seems to say that the Publish Page is just a front end to the ClickOnce settings.

Comment: Change your name to Holmes right now, sir.  I had no idea I've been using ClickOnce this entire time.  Go me.  I'm going to read through what you've linked and get back to you.