# Need help on upgrade of application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to know the best approach for updating an application.  The way I know is to replace the .exe files in your application file with the new updated one.  But I wonder how different applications do this while they are running and updates are downloaded from internet.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: You can't replace a program while it is running. You have to stop it, install the new version and then restart it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate process to search for udpates and replace the old exe file with the new one. As far as I know in Windows you can't modify an exe file which is being executed (in Linux you can).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a second application (Updater) that can close the running application, execute the installer (or copy over the new files for the new version) and then re-launch the application once the update is complete.

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418237/how-do-i-get-a-console-application-to-check-for-updates-without-using-clickonce) offers more details as to how to do this.